# Flash problem pepper flash

Tags: flash

All was fine apart from Chrome flash crashing in and you tube saying install html5 flash. Firefox was fine. Now no flash works in anything. How do i un-install pepper flash? I'm just giving up on Chrome working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to enter in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall pepper
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall freshplayerplugin 
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

and it might work fine this way.